# Hanging on Gnome Power Button Press

Tags: gnome, opensuse

I use OpenSUSE Leap 42.3.  My window manager is Gnome.  When I click the power button from the drop menu in the top right corner, the system hangs for probably a good 10-15 seconds.  How can I diagnose the cause of this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, do you have the [Caffeine](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/) extension activated?

Comment: I do, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine/issues/48) in the [Caffeine extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/) which causes GNOME shell to temporarily stop responding on first power button event. Disabling the extension should get rid of the issue.

As a replacement you may use another extension called [Keep Awake!](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1097/keep-awake/) which provides similar (but with fewer options) functionality or wait (or hope) for the Caffeine extension to get updated with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- I think modern Gnome default settings include a desktop fade effect on logout. If your display controller does not include the 3D accelerator feature that is used to implement that effect, it could cause an apparent hang. Disable the fade effect from Gnome settings to see if this could be the cause.
- Read the session log. Your home directory may have something like `~/.xsession-errors` that includes any error messages generated by your desktop environment components. You may have to login on the text console (or remotely with SSH) to move the log file of the old session to safety before a new GUI login overwrites it.
- Read the system logs: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is the system-wide log of the X server, and other files in the same directory may be useful too. If OpenSUSE Leap 42.3 uses `systemd`, then `journalctl -xb -1` might also be useful after a reboot, for viewing the last logged events before the previous shutdown.